# add / remove class and append to an unordered list navigation using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an unordered list styled as a horizontal nav-bar - in the last list item i have a search box with a class of pull-right as shown below...

```
 <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Coming Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">This Month</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Next Month</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Past Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li class="pull-right">
   <div id="event-serach-content">
    <form id="search-event" method="get" action="">
    <div class="event-search-box">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search events..." id="frm-search" name="s">
          </div>
    <div class="event-submit-btn">
            <button type="submit">Go</button>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>

    </li>
    </ul>

     </div>
<!-- navbar End //-->
```

I have the following jQuery that adds/removes class 'selected' with the click event and appends span tags. Is there a way to ignore the last list i.e don't add the selected class? The empty span tags have a Bg of a down arrow. Hope this makes sense, thanks in advance.

```
            $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".navbar ul li:first").addClass('selected').append('<span></span>');

                $(".navbar ul li").click(function(){
                     $(".navbar ul li").removeClass('selected').find('span').empty().remove();

                     $(this).addClass('selected');
                     if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
                         // $(".navbar ul li:last").removeClass('selected').find('span').empty().remove();
                          $(".navbar ul li").append('<span></span>')
                     }
                     return false
                });

            });
```

Comment: Why not target the "a" tag for the click event, you aren't using the A tags for real links...? :)

Comment: Hi Marco - no not at the moment, project is still in its infancy so I'm not sure what's happening there. I will re visit this when the time comes. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:not` and `:last` selectors:

```
$(".navbar ul li:not(:last)")
```

Comment: This is a better way of doing it as you only use one jQuery object

Comment: Thank you for your answers -  I had used the :not and :last but I just had errors in my syntax. This was a great help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the set of selected elements that you bind the click event to using `:not(:last)`

```
            $(".navbar ul li:not(:last)").click(function(){
                 $(".navbar ul li").removeClass('selected').find('span').empty().remove();

                 $(this).addClass('selected');
                 if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
                     // $(".navbar ul li:last").removeClass('selected').find('span').empty().remove();
                      $(".navbar ul li").append('<span></span>')
                 }
                 return false
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a conditional into your click function to check for the last child in this case.

```
$('.navbar ul li').click(function(e) {
    // If LI is not last child append class
    if ( ! $(this).is(':last-child') ) {
        $(".navbar ul li").removeClass('selected').find('span').empty().remove();
    }

    // Rest of code for click
});
```